# Return junk value for selectedRow in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a code which returns selected row for NStableView as under:

```
int status;
NSUInteger selectedRow = [tableView selectedRow];
if (selectedRow == 0)
    return;
```

But, when i have not selected any row in table view or if the tableview is empty, it returns junk value. How can i tackle with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-selectedRow` returns **signed** integer and you're using unsigned in your code. If there's no row selected method returns -1, so you're getting some overflowed value in your unsigned variable.

Answer (score 0):

The *first row* in the table is row zero. The placeholder for "no selected row" is `NSNotFound`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to get the table view's `selectedRowIndexes` and check the count of that set. An empty index set (count == 0) means no selection; if the index set is not empty (count > 0), at least one row is selected (the rows identified by the indexes in the set).